# Unable to get full VISA address that includes the serial number

Tags: python, raspbian, pyusb, pyvisa

I do not have any prior experience in Python and was trying to see if I can query information from a device with USB VISA address. I am running a Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) with a Python 3.5.3 Shell. The VISA packages for python was installed using pip3:

```
$ sudo pip3 install pyvisa-py
```

Since I am interfacing the device with USB interface, I installed the python USB package as well.

```
$ sudo pip3 install pyusb
```

When I use the generic commands as per [PyVISA website](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting.html), I am able to read the partial VISA address without the serial number as shown below:

```
>>> import visa
>>> rm = visa.ResourceManager()
>>> print(rm.list_resources())
Found a device whose serial number cannot be read. The partial VISA resource name is: USB0::2391::11032::???::0::INSTR
('ASRL/dev/ttyAMA0::INSTR',)
```

Here is the python VISA info:

```
$ python3 -m visa info 
Machine Details:    
    Platform ID:    Linux-4.14.62-v7+-armv7l-with-debian-9.4    
    Processor:      

Python:    
    Implementation: CPython    
    Executable:     /usr/bin/python3  
    Version:        3.5.3    
    Compiler:       GCC 6.3.0 20170124    
    Bits:           32bit    
    Build:          Jan 19 2017 14:11:04 (#default)    
    Unicode:        UCS4

PyVISA Version: 1.9.1

Backends:    
    ni:
      Version: 1.9.1 (bundled with PyVISA)
      Binary library: Not found    
    py:
      Version: 0.3.0
      TCPIP SOCKET: Available
      GPIB INSTR:
         Please install linux-gpib to use this resource type.
         No module named 'gpib'
      USB INSTR: Available via PyUSB (1.0.2). Backend: libusb1
      ASRL INSTR: Available via PySerial (3.2.1)
      USB RAW: Available via PyUSB (1.0.2). Backend: libusb1
      TCPIP INSTR: Available
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. How do I read the full VISA resource name? Without that, even if I try to force open the device with the full VISA address, it would throw another error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for my problem after referring to NI-VISA 17.0 read me file. USB devices are not accessible by VISA due to read only access. The solution on how and which file to edit were found from [LinuxQuestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-edit-etc-udev-rules-d-40-basic-permissions-rules-file-705646/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa/issues/212). The steps that I took are as follows:

To become root on a Linux system, in a terminal, issue the command

```
sudo -i
```

and give your login password when asked. Then give the comand as above. Please check your spelling / copying very carefully before you press

While here, to edit the USB permissions file, you need to give the following commands in a terminal:
Become root (as above). Notice how your terminal prompt has changed.
Back up the original file:

```
cp  /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules  /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules.BAK
```

Open the file with the nano editor:

```
nano  /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules
```

Edit the file by adding the following:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", MODE="0666", GROUP="usbusers"
```

Save the changes with "WriteOut" which is , press Enter to confirm the file name and location. Then "Exit" which is 
You'll need to restart udev so the changes are noticed:

```
/etc/init.d/udev  restart
```

Close the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

@Arun Kumar Worked for me (Linux-4.15.0-34-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic).
I just wanted to add to the answer that to make it work I had to create the "usbusers" group:

`sudo groupadd usbusers`

And add myself to the group:

`sudo usermod -a -G usbusers USERNAME`

Finally reboot...

Comment: This comment worked for me. For some reason, it wouldn’t work with a udev trigger, I had to do a reboot.